# Interface Requiring Function That Returns Task

Tags: .net, vb.net, async-await, task

I have an interface that requires a certain function which returns Task. In one of the classes that implement this interface, I don't need to do anything whatsoever in this function. However, this understandably presents me with a helpful warning: Function 'MoveToNextField' doesn't resturn a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used.

```vb
Public Function MoveToNextField() As Task Implements FormObjects.Interfaces.IViewer.MoveToNextField

End Function
```

This presents an issue as the code calling it (below) is going to await this function. If I fail to return anything, I'll get a null reference exception.

```vb
await objExample.MoveToNextField()
```

However, since I have nothing to await, changing the function to the below also presents me with a warning: This async function lacks 'Await' operators and so will run synchrounsly. Consider using the 'Await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'Await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

```vb
Public Async Function MoveToNextField() As Task Implements FormObjects.Interfaces.IViewer.MoveToNextField

End Function
```

So, my question is: What is the most correct way of solving this? The below code works and produces no errors, but I'm not convinced it is the best way:

```vb
Public Function MoveToNextField() As Task Implements FormObjects.Interfaces.IViewer.MoveToNextField
    Return Task.Run(Sub()
                    End Sub)
End Function
```

Comment: If you must have a method a body what about `Return Task.CompletedTask`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `Return Task.CompletedTask`.  This is useful in cases like the one you describe where you need to satisfy an interface method that returns a Task, but you have nothing to await in your concrete implementation.

```
Public Function MoveToNextField() As Task Implements FormObjects.Interfaces.IViewer.MoveToNextField
    Return Task.CompletedTask
End Function
```